# Something went wrong with driver update and now my screen is half the size

Tags: 12.04, nvidia

I'm a student on winter break so am away from my backup drives and can't just do a fresh install or dd my old working hard drive back into the machine or anything.

background (if you want):
I was having some stability problems (which I still haven't figured out quite yet) with qt creator: while trying to add a resource file to a new project, the thing would just insta-close on me. 10 min later I got an internal error message about unity which wasn't all that big of a deal at the time because it wasn't affecting anything else to m knowledge. I read around and heard of other people having similar problems with their unity and driver configurations and I was curious about gnome anyway so I tried the same thing in gnome and got the same result with qt creator so I figured it must be on the level of my drivers.

the problem:
I ran  apt-get update and apt-get install nvidia-current, rebooted and got a funky setup... the dock icons are the size of my thumb and everything is zoomed in to some size in the upper left-hand corner of my machine. Also, about 2.5 inches on either size of the screen simply aren't being used. The change of screen doesn't happen until the splash login screen. The Ubuntu loading screen is just like my old screen used to be and is still good resolution.

I have an nvidia geforce gt 640m card but am unsure about how to find any more information about it because 12.04 doesn't seem to know what driver I am using or anything whenever I go into the system settings to look around.

images:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/llbrF.png ... my desktop screenshot
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkI0U.png ... screenshot of reddit.com

I'm not sure why everything scaled the way it did or why I can't see half of my desktop anymore. Most of my documents and things were below the visible screen window and I can't access them. None of the scaling that you see in the pictures has been done by me.

needless to say the interface is really annoying and some programs don't have a left-right scroll bar...

PLEASE HELP!!

Comment: Have you tried going to System Settings > Monitors and change resolution?

Comment: yup. wouldn't let me choose anything other than 640x480

Answer (score 1):

After talking to a friend, I have come to viable solution:

```
cp /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf-20130101
sudo rm xorg.conf
```

reboot

Comment: Thats fun, I guess *something* created an xorg file with the wrong size. Ubuntu has a blank one these days, so renaming the old one caused the autodetected settings to work. If you had control alt-backspace enabled, which ubuntu dosen't you could simply restart X with that combo rather than rebooting